# Java BufferedImage in C++

Tags: java, c++, opencv, bufferedimage

I'm translating from Java to C++ an OpenCV project for university. I'm looking for a way to translate the Java BufferedImage in C++.

It is possible to translate that class in some way in C++?

Am I looking the problem from the wrong angle and I should use OpenCV objects like `IplImage` or `Mat`?

I'm translating a project that convert paper graph into a digital form. I'm posting the Java main function to make an example:

```
    String name = "";
    IplImage greyScaleGraph = null;
    // open up standard input
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out
            .println("Insert the name of an image from the Input Folder (ex graph.png):");
    String input = null;
    try {
        input = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IO error trying to read the input");
    }
    if (input != null) {
        if (input.contains("."))
            name = input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf('.'));
        else
            name = input;

        greyScaleGraph = ImageManager.loadGreyscaleImage(PATH + input);
        if (greyScaleGraph == null) {
            System.err.println("No image with that name found");
            System.err.println("--- exit ---");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    // IplImage greyScaleGraph = ImageManager.loadGreyscaleImage(PATH + NAME
    // + EXTENSION);
    ImageManager.ShowImage(greyScaleGraph, "GreyGraph", 512);

    // alternativa di openCV per la binarizzazione:
    IplImage bWImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(greyScaleGraph),
            IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvThreshold(greyScaleGraph, bWImage, 127, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    bWImage = Utility.reverse(bWImage);
    // IplImage bWImage = OtsuBinarize.otsuBinarize(greyScaleGraph);

    // cvReleaseImage(greyScaleGraph);

    IplImage result = ZhangSuenThinning.thinning(bWImage.asCvMat())
            .asIplImage();
    ImageManager.ShowImage(result, "Result after thinning", 512);

    IplImage houghLinesImage = HoughLines.houghLines(result,
            "probabilistic");
    ImageManager.ShowImage(bWImage, "bWImage", 512);
    ImageManager.ShowImage(houghLinesImage, "houghLinesImage", 512);

    IplImage noAxisImage = AxisManipulator.deleteAxis(result.clone(),
            houghLinesImage);
    // ImageManager.ShowImage(noAxisImage, "noAxisImage", 512);

    ConnectedComponents.findConnectedComponents(noAxisImage.clone(),
            "Connected Components");

    TicksFinder.FindTicks(noAxisImage);

    SymbolsFinder.connectedComponentsAnalysis(bWImage);

    SymbolsFinder.groupMinus();
    SymbolsFinder.groupParenthesis();
    TicksFinder.tickNumberCoupleFinder();

    IplImage symbolsImage = IplImage.createFrom(Utility.reverse(result
            .getBufferedImage()));
    SymbolsFinder.printSymbols(symbolsImage);

    SVGCreator.createSVG(name);
```

Comment: it's probably not nessecary to translate this class(BufferedImage is mostly used to translate from Mat to java's gui classes, and opencv comes with its own gui already), but please, show your code ! ( and definitely - cv::Mat, not IplImage* ! )

Comment: OpenCV has Java binding available, why not just use that?  What are you trying to actually do?

Comment: I've edited the question with the code. I think I took the problem from the wrong angle basically because i didn't understand fully the BufferedImage class.

Comment: unfortunately (very personal, biased opinion !), your javacv/Iplimage based code is no more useful today. rather [start from scratch](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3207/what-is-a-good-thinning-algorithm-for-getting-the-skeleton-of-characters-for-ocr/) using opencv's c++ api, than trying to translate any of your javacv based code.